# How to end a specific user session in Azure active directory

Tags: azure-active-directory

I'm developping a UI to manage Azure Active directory user's groups.
I noticed that for an already connected user, the change in the list of groups he bolongs to doesn't affect his credentials until he logout and log on again.

Is it possible to make a connected user session end (for exemple just after the change of his groups list) ? or make its session immediately take into account the change in its credentials ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait until the user signs in again to update the information. If needed though, you can [revoke](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/enterprise-users/users-revoke-access) the user's access and then allow it again. You do have to wait for the token to expire though, unless you [revoke the tokens](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/azuread/revoke-azureaduserallrefreshtoken?view=azureadps-2.0) themselves.

```
Revoke-AzureADUserAllRefreshToken
  -ObjectId <String>
  [<CommonParameters>]
```